# How to prove that the product of two projection matrices is zero?

Tags: proof-verification, products, projection-matrices

I now have $C_1$ and $C_2$, both are   $n\times{n}$  symmetric, idempotent matrices and $C_1+C_2=I_n$.
How do I prove that $C_1{C_2}=0$?

I'm supposed to use $a^T C_1 a- a^T C_1 a=0$ (for an arbitrary matrix $a$) to do the process.

I know I can have

$a^T C_1 a-a^T C_1 C_1 a=0$
                  $a^T C_1 a (I_n-C_1) =0 $
                  $a^T C_1 a C_2 =0  $
                  $a^T C_1 C_1 a C_2 C_2=0 $

But how can I get

$a^T (C_1 C_2)(C_2 C_1) a =0$

from above so I can have

$(C_1 C_2) (C_1 C_2)^T=0$

and thus conclude that

$C_1{C_2}=0$     ?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you get some mileage out of squaring $C_1+C_2$?

Comment: If it is true for an arbitrary matrix $a$, it is true for a specific matrix, for example $a=C_1$.

Comment: Or, even quicker: Start with $C_1+C_2=I$ and multiply $C_1$ on both sides. We do not even need the two matrices to be symmetric.

Comment: I don't think the derivation of $a^T C_1 a (I_n-C_1)=0$ is correct; instead, $a^T C_1 a-a^T C_1 C_1 a=a^T C_1(I_n-C_1)a=a^T C_1 C_2 a$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are symmetric, $C_1C_2=C_2C_1$; and since they are idempotent,

$$I_n=(C_1+C_2)^2=C_1^2 +C_1C_2+C_2C_1+C_2^2 = (C_1+C_2) + 2C_1C_2 = I_n + 2C_1C_2.$$

Thus, $C_1C_2=0$.

Comment: $C_1$ and $C_2$ being symmetric does not imply that $C_1C_2=C_2C_1$. For example, take $C_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $C_2=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ (in fact these are idempotent as well).